# Changed home folder name and lost everything

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I tried to change the home folder name on my mac by using this sudo code in the terminal:

```
sudo mv /Users/old_name /Users/new_name
```

And I lost everything, every document, every file. Its like my user profile has totally been reset.

How do I get it all back?

Comment: Can I ask why you did it? What are you trying to achieve? Note that you should be very careful with `sudo` commands unless you absolutely know what you're doing (or have a backup — do you have one?).

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Preferences → Users & Groups and right click on your user. It will appear an `Avanced Options` menu. Then replace `Home Directory` with `/Users/new_name`.

Logout and login again and should appear all your stuff.

Comment: I think the only reason this answer doesn't have a lot of upvotes is because people are logged out of everything when they try to solve this problem! haha I had to come back here after fixing it to upvote it. Thank you, unsung hero!

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the change: `sudo mv /Users/new_name /Users/old_name`

Once reversed, you can change your user name the way Apple recommends:

1. Launch **System Preferences** and click on **Users & Groups**.
2. Control-click on the profile name that you want to change and click on **Advanced Options**.
3. Change the Account name and/or Full name and then click **OK**
4. Reboot your computer for the changes to take effect.